# How to check mail client exists from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I trying to find a way to check if the mail client is existing from AngularJS code. I have a code to bring up the e-mail client as "window.location.href = "mailto:<..>". The app crashes when I disable all mail clients.

Background: The app is a HTML5 Hybrid mobile app. Front-end: IonicFramework/AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check if mail exists in javascript-since it's a **client side** language. You can use it in c# or any other server-side language if you would like to.
Of course you can use Ajax but it would use a server side method.